# SharePoint 2010 subsite doesnt open

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, site-collection, central-administration, farm-admin

We have 3 SharePoint Front ends server and I can access top level site and other site collections. But there is 1 SharePoint subsite that I cant access from central administration and also if any users tries to access the page it loads and loads without any result finally shows page cant be displayed.

Any reason why this is happening only to one subsite? The site was working from last 1 year all of sudden I have seen this problem. Any thoughts would be appreciated.

If I do IISreset page loads but after some time it goes to same problem. I am not sure where the problem lies and how can I trouble shoot this issue??

**Update**
URL for the subsite looks like below 
abc.com/DEF/FRA/FRACalendar

Problem looks with the list as other parts of sites loads without any problem. List has around 1400 items, we have event receivers on this list and timer job as well which would send an email to users when task is due.

When timer job runs and sends an email URL in body of the email will look like below. It takes lot of time when user clicks on the link.
abc.com/DEF/FRA/FRACalendar/Lists/FRA%20Calendar/DispForm.aspx?ID=1637.

And also, Sub site loads in server, once I do  iis reset.

Answer (score 0):

If it is subsite then you cant access it from the central admin. Because in Central admin you can only see the site collections.

you could do the following

- check the event logs for any clue of issue
- check the ULS logs for the clue
- You can also use the fiddler to troublshoot it.
- check the content Database where site is reside, i.e space
- check if their is any site quota issue
- check if you have customization i.e heavy workflows, webpart or large lists etc

Lastly, if you can share some kind of screen shot what u get on screen and url, it will help

Comment: is it your subsite"http://sharepointfinance.gcm.com/Finance/FRA" and in central admin it is listed as /Finance/FRA, right?

Comment: Hi waqas, I had updated the question. URL for the subsite looks like below abc.com/DEF/FRA/FRACalendar and we have list called FRACalendar under the subsite

Comment: Now it's make sense...u have event receiver, u should check event receiver becz if Iis reset fix the issue that's mean event receiver started fresh not from cache....I think it is your site collection on managed path /der/...because sub site never shows in central admin...disable event receiver then test

Comment: I tried deactivating the event receiver feature from site features and it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description , iis reset fix the issue temporarily.

So you could verify if the pool actually stops, if so ,That could be  an issue  on  iis worker process.

Or verify app pool  user account  AD policy.

Comment: pool doesn't stop at all.